# read excel file contents and insertion into database

Tags: php, symfony

hello I would like to read an excel file and insert its contents in the database given in my web

```
<form  class="form-analyste"  method="POST" action="{{ path('Importer_dark_cell')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152000000">
 Fichier : <input type="file" name="avatar">
                <li class="li">

 <input  type="submit" name="envoyer" value="Envoyer le fichier">
 </li>
 </ul>
 </h5>
```

`

web but I when I click send I'll always File not found!
© e import stopped. I tried to find on the internet but I found the same answer that can help me please I'm stuck in this point: (I can not move on before setting  (

```
public function importer_dark_cellAction(){
    $session =$this->get('request')->getSession() ;
        $user_name = $session->get('user_name');

    $fichier=$_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
/* On ouvre le fichier à importer en lecture seulement */
if (file_exists($fichier))
$fp = fopen("$fichier", "r"); 
else
{ /* le fichier n'existe pas */
echo "Fichier introuvable !<br>Importation stoppée.";
exit();
}  $host = "172.25.5.227"; 
$user = "stgzouaoui"; 
$password = "stg"; 
$bdd = "stg_zouaoui_dev"; 
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ("impossible de se connecter au serveur" ); 
        mysql_select_db($bdd) or die ("impossible de se connecter a la base de donnees" );
  while (!feof($fp)) /* Et Hop on importe */
    { /* Tant qu'on n'atteint pas la fin du fichier */ 
       $ligne = fgets($fp,4096); /* On lit une ligne */  

       /* On récupère les champs séparés par ; dans liste*/
       $liste = explode( ";",$ligne);  

       /* On assigne les variables */ 
       $Nom_cell = $liste[0]; 
       $cmts = $liste[1]; 

       /* Ajouter un nouvel enregistrement dans la table */ 
       $query = "INSERT INTO dark_cell VALUES('$Nom_cell','$cmts')"; 
       $result= MYSQL_QUERY($query); 

       if(mysql_error())
        { /* Erreur dans la base de donnees, surement la table qu'il faut créer */
           print "Erreur dans la base de données : ".mysql_error();
           print "<br>Importation stoppée.";
           exit();
        } 
       else /* Tout va bien */
         print "$Nom_cell $cmts <br>";
     } 

     echo "<br>Importation terminée, avec succès."; 

     /* Fermeture */ 
     fclose($fp); 
     MYSQL_CLOSE(); 

   break;
```

Comment: And the enctype of your html form?

Comment: lack of copy i have edit my code

Comment: I'd say you don't read a spreadsheet file, but a csv file. Maybe you exported the spreadsheet to csv format? php comes with a csv reading function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Please edit in your code

```
$fichier=$_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
```

Comment: I have Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\alerteurs1\src\Admin\BlogBundle\Controller\GestionAlerteController.php line 947
and line 947:       $cmts = $liste[1];

Comment: what to put in the separator if we explode. xlsx file